# hive difference between insert and load data

Tags: hadoop, hive, insert, mapreduce

I am new to **Hadoop** and **Hive**, and I am confused about hive's `insert into` and `load data` statements.

When I execute `INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME (field1, field2) VALUES(value1, value2);`, hiveserver will execute mapReduce task.

When I execute `LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH PATH_TO_MY_DATA INTO TABLE TABLE_NAME;`, it only loads data from the file and does nothing else.

I wrote a program with Python, here is my problem, if I use pyhs2 and use the `insert` statement to save data records, each record will execute a MapReduce task, and it is very slow.
Should I first save my data somewhere, and later use the `load data` statement to load it?

Answer (score 4):

**Load**
Hive does not do any transformation while loading data into tables. Load operations are currently pure copy/move operations that move datafiles into locations corresponding to Hive tables.

**Insert**

Query Results can be inserted into tables by using the insert clause.

```
INSERT INTO TABLE tablename PARTITION (partcol1[=val1], partcol2[=val2] ...) select_statement FROM from_statement;
```

in load all the data which in file is copied into table, in insert you can put data based on some condition.

**your solution**

for every single row you execute your given hql so every time map reduce run.

if you want to execute your query in single mapreduce then

```
INSERT INTO TABLE students
  VALUES ('fred flintstone', 35, 1.28), ('barney rubble', 32, 2.32);
```

create a single query and execute it. If you have more records in this condition you can make it a batch.

Comment: Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score -2):

INSERT OVERWRITE will overwrite any existing data in the table or partition
and INSERT INTO will append to the table or partition keeping the existing
data ([ref at apache.org](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DML#LanguageManualDML-InsertingdataintoHiveTablesfromqueries)).